# How to replace a variable value in polymer {{}} mustache

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer-1.0

Hi I am trying to change the value dynamically in polymer1.0 like

{{forms.form.**firebaseKey**.registrationNumber}}

It return undefined , If i replace the same with -JzqYMbZ1fi0nROqeVFi which is value of form.__firebaseKey then it prints the exact val.

Can someone please figure out how can I change the value dynamically.

Note: I am trying to printing this inside a dom repeat template.

Comment: Why don't u assign this dynamic value to new prop, then "echo" it with double mustache?

Comment: I arleady echo  {{forms.form.firebaseKey.registrationNumber}} with double mustache.  will it be feasible to use this like {{forms.{{new_prop}}.registrationNumber}} ?

Comment: I think you have to provide a better example of what you are doing(/trying to do), so that we can see if you are doing something wrong. I'm not quite sure I understand what you wanna do.